# Custom List Scrolling behavior in List View - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I'm trying to do something similar to PlayStore app. On the app details page you can see a scroll view which has a horizontal scrolling - "app screen images" and also some details below it like, Description, Reviews, etc...

[image: Sample Image Screen Shot]

**My Question is**: In the PlayStore app, when you scroll the *image screen shots* horizontally, the vertical scroll is locked and the whole view dose not scroll. Only when you touch and scroll some where below the *screen shot images* , you can scroll to see other details.

Here is where I'm stuck, Is it possible to do the same with a listView? I have a list view with a custom header View which detects for horizontal scroll gestures, (right to left and viceversa). At that time when the user is touching the header, I do not want the whole view to scroll as a normal listview dose when it has more items. Can some one guide me a solution for this? Check out the PlayStore app in your device for a clear understanding.

Thanks a bunch in advance. I would owe you a drink some day.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you detect the gestures and implement the horizontal scrolling yourself, when there's a special control: `HorizontalScrollView` which already does this?

I don't know the internal details of Google Play app, but I would put the gallery of screenshots in a custom view, and this custom view to be wrapped in a `HorizontalScrollView`. Then add this custom view as a header to the `ListView` (basically how you begun).

As long as the scrolling directions are on different axis - the horizontal scrolling is done on X axis, and the vertical scroll on Y axis - there shouldn't be any problems in holding this.

**Post Scriptum:**
When you scroll the image screenshots horizontally in the Google Play app, I suppose there's a `GalleryView` instead of HorizontalScrollView, which can hold this type of transitions.

Comment: Well, sorry Andy for not being very clear with my question, Please bear with me. I'm not looking to implement horizontal scrolling in the custom header view. I'm trying to detect gesture movements - (right and left). My custom header view listens for touch event  `event.getX();` and draws accordingly. Please let me know If I'm still not clear. I can explain... Thanks.